# Annoying Viber notification

Tags: notification, viber

Can I somehow put Viber notification [icon](http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2H/O8/DQsFWMS/screenshot-from-2014-01-.png) on top of the Unity panel (near Dropbox and others)?! It's pretty ugly to stay in top left corner...

Comment: Hi @Marko. I also have the same problem, and it is quite annoying. Did you find anything that solves the problem?

Comment: Hi @JimBlum! Unfortunately no, I gave up on this.

Answer (score 19):

### Solution - use Viber wrapper to launch the program

To fix this, you need to install *Viber Indicator* package, which is a wrapper for Viber.

Once it's installed, use `viberwrapper-indicator` (showing gray icon in the notification area) instead of `viber` (which shows the purple icon).

You may also later add `viberwrapper-indicator` to startup programms.

### Installation

Here's how to install the indicator wrapper via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install viberwrapper-indicator
```

Alternatively download the `.deb` file, and install it manually:

- [Index of /nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/v/viberwrapper-indicator](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/v/viberwrapper-indicator/)

After the download of the `.deb` file: `sudo dpkg -i viberwrapper-indicator_0.1.1-git20150611-webupd8-0_amd64.deb`

After installation it will look like you - and others would - want it:

[image]

Note the new icon in the notification area.

### Sources

- [Viber Wrapper Indicator Hides Floating Viber Icon, Adds AppIndicator Support ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/viber-wrapper-indicator-hides-floating.html)

**Related Pages**:

- [GitHub: karas84/viberwrapper-indicator](https://github.com/karas84/viberwrapper-indicator)

Comment: I think I used this once and worked but not any more. Any idea for another solution to remove the floating icon from the top left of the screen?

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Didn't work form me on Ubuntu 14.10 too.

Comment: The answer here does not point out that you should launch viber indicator not viber itself. From article: `launch Viber Indicator from the Dash / menu, instead of launching Viber itself`. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works as it should.

Comment: @IvanIvanić I launch Viberwrapper instead of viber. However, both viber's AND viberwrapper's icons show, with the one being at the left top corner. So, yes, this does not work for me at ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This package is dependent on python package which is no longer exists. Is there any other chance?

Answer (score 8):

you can do it by :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-$(lsb_release -sc)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Log out and Log in.

Comment: How to roll back to the standard view? Now I have the following artifact with random applications in the tray http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38375218/skype.png

Comment: I've fix my issue. The issue was caused by mono application.

Answer (score 0):

This github project https://github.com/karas84/viberwrapper-indicator worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from this Viber Wrapper, I think is possible with dconf-tools to change whitelist applications to ['all'].

Answer (score 0):

Run Viber with `StartMinimized` parameter.

```
/opt/viber/Viber StartMinimized
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded Viber on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to the latest version:

```
dpkg -s viber
Package: viber
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: non-free/net
Installed-Size: 350908
Maintainer: Viber Media Inc <support@viber.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 6.0.1.5
```

And the icon appears in the right place:

[image]

Congrats!