# Viber notification is not in the right position

Tags: unity, 14.04, icons, viber

This question is basically the same question as [Annoying Viber notification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399774/annoying-viber-notification), but the guy there didn't get any answer.

So I am also posting it as I couldn't find any answer anywhere.

[image]

As you can see there is a very annoying icon of viber on the top left, that is on top of the exit symbol "x" of the other applications. Is it possible to remove that thing completely, or to move it at the place where the skype or the dropbox is?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition installed.

Comment: I posted an answer that works ^ there: http://askubuntu.com/a/551816/36315

Comment: Just because he didn't accept one doesn't mean one doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To put in the right position:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-$(lsb_release -sc)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Log out and log in.
And it's working.

Comment: Excellent! As a sort of offtopic, how to make the same for the Skype icon? It's not showing in the tray now.

Comment: I was using this option, and it worked. Now, viber is at the left top corner again, and these commands do not any longer work for me. Do you know why?

Comment: ppa doesnt work aymore

Answer (score 25):

This has already been fixed, Install the following wrapper via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install viberwrapper-indicator
```

Alternatively download the deb file, and install it manually:

- [Index of /nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/v/viberwrapper-indicator](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/v/viberwrapper-indicator/)

After installation it will look like you want it:

[image]

**Source**:

- [Viber Wrapper Indicator Hides Floating Viber Icon, Adds AppIndicator Support ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/viber-wrapper-indicator-hides-floating.html)

**Related Pages**:

- [GitHub: karas84/viberwrapper-indicator](https://github.com/karas84/viberwrapper-indicator)

Comment: This app is good, especially because the indicator is colorless; but it prevents Viber to remember last opened conversation.

Comment: Thanks @blade19899. However, when I start viberwrapper, both viberwrapper'ss AND viber's icons show, with the viber's icon being at the left top corner again... So this does not work for me at all. Do you know why is that, or how I can fix that?