# How to move viber notification icon to the right position in 14.10?

Tags: indicator, 14.10, viber

I installed viber in ubuntu 14.04, and it had notification icon position problem, which could be fixed by doing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481614/viber-notification-is-not-in-the-right-position). But after upgrade, icon moved back to the original position, and I cannot move it back by fllowing these instructions. Is there a solution for 14.10? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and decided to test using the method the worked with 14.04 with changing "trusty" to "utopic" and it worked. I'm not sure if this is a permanent fix as I have not been using this for more than a day.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-utopic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After complete log out and log back in and the icon should move to the right. Hopefully this works for you.