# How to remove viber icon from left top corner

Tags: unity, icons, viber

I have viber icon in my left-top cornet. There is solution how to fix it - [How to move viber notification icon to the right position in 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541017/how-to-move-viber-notification-icon-to-the-right-position-in-14-10)
But when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get errors:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                 
404  Not Found
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages              
404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gurqn/systray-utopic/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gurqn/systray-utopic/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've ubuntu 14.04. How can I fix it?

Also I've tryed this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install viberwrapper-indicator
```

But icon in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You added a 14.10 PPA to 14.04 - so first remove it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:gurqn/systray-utopic
```

Now add the 14.04 PPA :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I've done it, no errors occurred, restart my comp, but ubuntu icon still there. Other suggestions?

Comment: Ubuntu icon?...

Comment: No, viber icon. Like on this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/stgw2.png