# Viber Notification in wrong position blocking the 'x' in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, viber

Please help me to move the viber notification to the right spot. The standard solutions for available for 14.04 does not help.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viber notification is not in the right position](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481614/viber-notification-is-not-in-the-right-position)

Comment: @astrob0t he says that "The standard solutions for available for 14.04 does not help. " so probably he has seen the answers mentioned on that question.