# Viber icon blocking the "x"

Tags: 14.10, viber

It's a known problem, but the standard solution doesn't seem to work for me any more.
You can see the problem and the usual solution here:

[Viber notification is not in the right position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481614/viber-notification-is-not-in-the-right-position)

It helped me fix the problem on Ubuntu 14.04, but today I have updated to 14.10, and the viber icon is now back on the same spot, blocking the "x", and the solution posted in that post doesn't seem to work anymore. Has anyone managed to move the icon on 14.10?

Comment: @KasiyA, why would you say that?  The question specifically says that question does NOT apply to 14.10...

Comment: @psusi If you visit again that you will see I have edited that to cover all Ubuntu version after I seen this question here.

Comment: Clicked to fast. Don't dupe a Q to another dupe: Oldest Question: http://askubuntu.com/q/399774/36315.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for Ubuntu 14.10 appears to be in a different repository than the fix for Ubuntu 14.04

Enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-utopic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then log out and log back in again.