# Viber indicator not working

Tags: unity, icons, indicator, viber

So I installed Viber on my Ubuntu 14.04 and had the realisation that the notification icon was at the wrong place (top left instead of with the other icons on the tray).

I followed the instructions at [Annoying Viber notification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399774/annoying-viber-notification) and installed the viber indicator program. This was working fine for a while, but at some point (possibly after updates) viber indicator can no longer launch. I tried re-installing it but is still refuses to launch. I can still launch Viber normally but that doesn't help because the indicator is again at the wrong position.

**Update:**

For anyone who may run into this in the future, as of (possibly) version 6 of the Linux client for Viber, the notification is behaving correctly without the need of any other packages to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application up to date?
If not download and install the current version from the Viber official website.
That worked for the issues I had. Hope it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Viber icon not working image]

After following the instructions from [Annoying Viber notification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399774/annoying-viber-notification) and installing the viber indicator program (`viberwrapper-indicator`), start the "Menu editor" and editing Viber application running command

from: `/opt/viber/Viber`  to  `dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber`,
You find that Viber starts with a working icon on the tray.

Works for Xubuntu 14.04. :)

Step by step:

1. Download Viber for debian eg: [download link Viber Debian 64bit](http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb)
2. install by left clicking on viber.deb in your download folder
3. Download and install Viberwrapper indicator
4. edit Viber start file:

   ```
   mousepad /home/YOUR_NAME/.local/share/applications/viber.desktop
   ```

change

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Exec=/opt/viber/Viber
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Application;Network;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Exec=dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Application;Network;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

save/overwrite it

5. Run Viber app in your start menu (not Viber indicator).

I have same issues for Dropbox and I find these solution:[Answer: new workaround, proposed by File C., is "dbus-launch dropbox start -i".](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64)

I added a little change and tried it on Viber, and it works for me.

Comment: Just adding dbus-launch at Viber launcher on Ubuntu 22 is enough. Thank you for solving it