# Why do I have 2 Viber appicons on my tray

Tags: icons, indicator, ubuntu-gnome, system-tray, viber

If I restart extension Ubuntu Appindicators, then only one icon stays.

[image]

Ubuntu is 21.10 and Viber is 16.1.0.37

If I grep Viber in processes, situation is same, before and after restarting appindicators extension...

```
root@mypc:/home/user# ps -afx | grep Vib
  13244 ?        SLl    0:01  |   \_ /opt/viber/Viber
  13264 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ /opt/viber/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=zygote --no-zygote-sandbox --application-name=ViberPC --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --lang=en-US
  13265 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ /opt/viber/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=zygote --application-name=ViberPC --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --lang=en-US
  13267 ?        S      0:00  |           \_ /opt/viber/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=zygote --application-name=ViberPC --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --lang=en-US
  13313 pts/0    S+     0:00  |                   \_ grep --color=auto Vib
```

Comment: Try reinstalling Viber. Even after uninstalling Viber do you still see Viber app? then you might have installed the twice.

Comment: Nope, once, already tried that... But below dbus fixes problem...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have solved issue by following this related answer

[Viber indicator not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774620/viber-indicator-not-working?rq=1)

after editing **viber.desktop** in **/usr/share/applications**

Changing line

```
Exec=/opt/viber/Viber
```

to:

```
Exec=dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber %u
```

Appindicator icon is working fine.