# Viber Tray Icon disappear after upgrade to 18.2 with Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: icons, system-tray, viber

Viber Tray Icon located at the top disappeared after upgrading from Viber 16.? to Viber 18.2.  This happened in ubuntu 20.04 and also 22.04.

viber installed by downloading the deb package from viber.com and using the command "sudo dpkg -i viber.deb".

The Viber Tray Icon is useful to indicate new messages when the viber window is hidden or minimized.  It is also used to quit/exit the viber program properly.

Other than this, viber 18.2 seems to work properly in ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.

Any help to recover the tray icon?

Comment: Have been in contact with Viber support about this, but there is no meaningful answer, apart from "reinstall viber and restart your computer", yet.

Comment: just downloaded and installed viber 20.3.0.1 and the icon works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with a fix explained in the link below, although needed to install `dbus-x11` as `dbus-launch` was missing:

[Viber indicator not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774620/viber-indicator-not-working)

Edit Viber desktop launcher, it lives in

```
/home/YOUR_NAME/.local/share/applications/viber.desktop
```

change

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Exec=/opt/viber/Viber
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Application;Network;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Exec=dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Application;Network;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288676)

Comment: Good Day, dbus-x11 is already installed.  I tried running on the command line 'dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber' but icon still does not show up.  Perhaps I am missing something else on the steps to resolve this issue?